# How to determine optimal sampling frequency for an ADC to reduce noise?

Tags: arduino, sampling, esp32, adc

Besides iterating through values, is there a good method for determining what the optimal sampling frequency/ averaging period is when sampling a voltage through an ADC to reduce noise?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate. You should sample at more than twice than the bandwidth of the analog signal.

Comment: As @timkay said, it depends on the frequencies that you want, and the frequencies that you don't want. For a low pass filter, I just use this: `out = out + (in - out)/16`

Cypress has application notes (AN2276 and AN2099) that explain the design. (They says AN2276 is obsolete, but we want only the first two pages.)

[link](https://www.cypress.com/file/127091) [link](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-47808/l/cypress-an2276-application-note-for-implementation-of-binary-weighted-single-pole-iir-low-pass-filters-in-psoc-1)